# How to get details of Facebook's "User shared a link" post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are some posts on my timeline which are links shared via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog. However, the API does not return any description with the link, and only this:

```
{ story: 'ABC DEF shared a link.',
       created_time: '2016-01-22T16:09:14+0000',
       id: 'xxx_yyy' 
}
```

I want to be able to find out the link which I shared, is it possible?

Comment: What is returning that?

Answer (score 1):

Use **link** in fields to get the link that you shared along with story and time.

Eg: `/{post_id}?fields=link,created_time,story`